# How can I resize the length of an card in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Well, I want to standardize the  width equal to the  above, but I'm not getting any way ... I've tried margin's, width and others, but none if you want to change the size of the card. I want to leave default, do you recommend me some command or am I doing wrong? all the css commands I did was in home.scss, thank you all.

[Watch the print of my app here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APHgh.png)

```css
page-home {

  .bg{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00A399 0%, #fafafa 400%);
  }

  .bg-ions{
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.2;
  }

  .btn{
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.2;
    color:white;
  }

  ion-input{
    color:#FAFAFA;
  }

  ion-textarea{
    color:#FAFAFA;
  }

  ion-card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }

  ion-card-content{
    margin-left:-2%;
  }

  ion-item{
    width:50%;
  }

  .summ{
    color:#000;
  }

  ::placeholder {
    color: white;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
  }

  :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: white;
  }

  ::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: white;
  }

}
```

```html
<br>
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      HybridSumm
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="bg">

  <ion-item class="bg-ions">
    <ion-label class="div-pai" color="primary" stacked>Title</ion-label>
    <ion-input placeholder="Ex: The Bio-informatics" style="color:white;"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <br>
  <ion-item class="bg-ions">
    <ion-label color="primary" stacked >Text</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea placeholder="Place the text that you want to summarize." ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="test"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
  <br>
  <button ion-button outline style="background: white">Summarize</button>
  <button ion-button>Test</button>

  <br><br>

  <ion-card>

    <ion-card-header>
      Card Header
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>
      {{test}}
    </ion-card-content>

  </ion-card>




</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ionic set some properties by default, and the only way to override them, is by giving them the **!important** rule.

It is maybe not the best practice, but it works, and ionic gives us not very much sass variables to overwrite some things.

It works for me adding this in the following SCSS rules in your code:

```
  ion-card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
```

[image]

I hope it works for you.